# Listing maven dependencies in a directory

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-dependency

I want to get all the maven dependencies list for a directory containing multiple projects. I can go inside each project and use command `mvn dependency:tree` and consolidate all of them manually.

Is there anyway (script or command) i can get consolidate list for all the project dependencies within parent directory.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a dummy project, add all your projects as dependencies and then call `dependency:list` on this dummy project.

Comment: thanks. I think this will give me exactly what i am looking for.